# Building caching structure for list of IDs and Json Objects

Tags: python, json, caching, redis, memcached

I'm looking to build a more efficient caching structure for a User's profile feed of images on a website. This feed is paginated. Therefore my selects in both the database and the cache will use an offset / page number.

My code is in Python and my caching system is in Redis. I'm using pagination to retrieve an offset of IDs, cache them, then uses those IDs to retrieve JSON blob objects from a database.

There are two types of tables that are involved with building a feed of images. There are "Object" tables which contain an id, json blob, and timestamp, and then there are "Mapping" tables which contain a mapping of IDs from one Object table to another Object table. For example:

**users (object table)**

- id
- username
- data (JSON)
- date (timestamp)

**images (object table)**

- id
- data (JSON)
- date (timestamp)

**user_has_images (mapping table)**

- user_id
- image_id
- date (timestamp)

To build a feed, we would do the following:

1. Get `user_id` from Users table (based on username from a url).
2. Use `user_id` to get Image IDs from `user_has_images`.
3. Use the Image IDs to get the Image json objects from the `images`

Each part of this process is cached. That caching structure currently looks like this:
 1. User object is cached as single object.
 2. Page 1 is viewed, `User_has_images` mapping is cached as `user_profile_ids:{user_id}:{page_number}`
 3. Image objects are cached as a list as one json object with the key `user_profile_images:{page_number}`

The problem I'm having with this structure is that if a user makes an edit to one of their images, it doesn't appear on the site until the Image objects cache expires.

The longer the cache is, the longer the user has to wait to see it, then the user questions if their action on the site worked or not.

Here are my two potential solutions to this problem:

1. **Expire multiple caches.** Each time a user makes an edit to their Image object, we try to find the cache that the image may exist in and either expire the cache or update it. The downside to this is that there are A LOT of different feeds on the site and at any given time we don't know which ones the image is in because there is no reference to the actual Image's ID.
2. **Cache the Image objects individually.** We would store each Image Object individually in the cache so that we could look them up by `image_id`. Once we've retrieved the `user_id => image_id` pairing, we would look in the cache for each image object using the `image_id`. When a user makes an edit to the image object, we only have to update it in one cache location if it was still in the cache. The potential downside here is if a feed of Images is requested and the actual= Image object is not in the cache, we would need to look up that image in the database (not sure if this would happen often). The second potential downside would be the expiration time of the individual image object if it occurred in multiple feeds (maybe this wouldn't be a problem?).

**Any thoughts or suggestions?**

Comment: Can you please clarify in your question how the cache by page number is related to user images ? You could track each image in a set more like the database user_has_images table is.

Comment: @Niloct It's related because it groups them into one cache key.  When that happens you don't know if the Image ID is within that cache key or not. I outlined the current implementation and a proposed implementation. "You could track each image in a set" is what I do currently.

Comment: Do you duplicate image json for each feed in each it appears ? Reading your post again makes me agree that you should keep only the image id in each feed, and cache each image info in single separate Redis key (or in a hash).

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Each time a feed is cached, the image json is added to that particular feed cache. So if that image appears in 100 feeds, it would be in each of those feed object caches 100 times. Do you see any potential downsides to the solution of caching each image into it's own key?

Comment: Well, duplicating the entire image object database in memory would be something bad, but I can't see a better solution. If it expires in all feeds, you have to decide if you remove the image object from Redis. If it expires in some feeds, the advantage of keeping image object caches separated from image uses is clear.

Comment: Say you're caching each image object separately, the one tricky problem I see is how do you decide on the cache expiration when the image appears in multiple different feeds?

Comment: When user updates image, you update the image object in hash/simple key, and further image listings will look at the updated image when fetching the image object from Redis. You fetch from Redis at every feed listing.

Comment: Yep I'm with you on that part, but what if you access an uncached feed containing Image A, then the image objects for that feed are set to expire in 5 hours, but then you visit a second uncached feed that also contains Image A, would you just extend the cache duration? Now that I've written that out it seems logical to just extend it...

Comment: You got this :) Are you using EXPIRE command ?

Comment: I do when setting the IDs in their respective cache, but I've been using SET with an expiration for the Objects. Mainly because with the ID's I was using RPUSH to a list.